# How to make a Javascript object answer to any method call?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I need to override a buggy library for a specific browser, but I can't just remove it since it "works" for all the other browsers.

I was trying to accomplish something of the following (like Ruby sending messages to methods):

- override the libraries object:

  var lib = {}
- override any call to this empty object to answer as if I was invoking this code:

  lib.xxx = function(){}

is it even possible to do in Javascript?

Comment: Not yet. ES6 introduces proxies which can intercept any property access (also to non-existing properties).

Comment: firefox alone (afaik) has https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod